# How can I dynamically calculate the optimum UpdateBatchSizefor an ADO.NET DataAdapter

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a method in my project that updates my SQL tables using an ADO.NET DataAdapter.

Now some of these tables can be quite large with maybe 5000 rows and some contan only a few rows of data.  What I want to be able to do is automatically calculate the optimum UpdateBatchSize for each table, based on the size of the DataTable.

The aproach I have taken so far is to use the following Extension Method:

```
public static void SetBatchUpdateSize(this DbDataAdapter adapter, int rowCount)
{
     if (rowCount <= 5)
     {
         adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 5;
     }
     else if (rowCount <= 1000)
     {
         adapter.UpdateBatchSize = rowCount/2;
     }
     else
     {
         adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 500;
     }
 }
```

This does work but I seem to be getting a performance hit on smaller tables.

For completeness here is how I set the size on the adapter:

```
var db = dbAccessLayer.CreateConnection();

try
{
     adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = db;
     adapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
     adapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = transaction;
     SetTimeout(timeout);
     adapter.SetBatchUpdateSize(dataTable.Rows.Count);
     int result = adapter.Update(Table);
     adapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = null;
     return result;
}
catch (Exception)
{
     dataTable.RejectChanges();
     throw;
}
```

There seems to be lots of speculation on the performance beneftis of update batches but no concrete facts on the optimum relationship.  I'm finding I am having issues with SQL Updates over low speed and poor quality connections so Im looking at ways to optimise this as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you have more bigger updatebatchsize than in one go that much data has to be transferred over the wire so very large UpdateBatchSize does not make much difference. In contrast , smaller size will perform better.

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question.  What is the relationship between connection speed, batch size and table size.  How can I arrive at an optimum solution without just picking some arbitrary values and hoping for the best.  You say smaller sizes work better but this is clearly not the case.  If I have 1000 rows in by table and a batchsize of 2 I end up with 500 calls to SQL, clearly not efficient.